# Need Help to remove a jQuery slider script "function"

Tags: jquery, function, slider

I'm adding a slider to a website but I don't like one of the functions it uses. I would like to remove the slide-down & slide-up image description function from this jQuery script.

**Script:**

```
(function($){  

    $.fn.s3Slider = function(vars) {       

        var element     = this;
        var timeOut     = (vars.timeOut != undefined) ? vars.timeOut : 4000;
        var current     = null;
        var timeOutFn   = null;
        var faderStat   = true;
        var mOver       = false;
        var items       = $("#" + element[0].id + "Content ." + element[0].id + "Image");
        var itemsSpan   = $("#" + element[0].id + "Content ." + element[0].id + "Image span");

        items.each(function(i) {

            $(items[i]).mouseover(function() {
               mOver = true;
            });

            $(items[i]).mouseout(function() {
                mOver   = false;
                fadeElement(true);
            });

        });

        var fadeElement = function(isMouseOut) {
            var thisTimeOut = (isMouseOut) ? (timeOut/2) : timeOut;
            thisTimeOut = (faderStat) ? 10 : thisTimeOut;
            if(items.length > 0) {
                timeOutFn = setTimeout(makeSlider, thisTimeOut);
            } else {
                console.log("Poof..");
            }
        }

        var makeSlider = function() {
            current = (current != null) ? current : items[(items.length-1)];
            var currNo      = jQuery.inArray(current, items) + 1
            currNo = (currNo == items.length) ? 0 : (currNo - 1);
            var newMargin   = $(element).width() * currNo;
            if(faderStat == true) {
                if(!mOver) {
                    $(items[currNo]).fadeIn((timeOut/6), function() {
                        if($(itemsSpan[currNo]).css('bottom') == 0) {
                            $(itemsSpan[currNo]).slideUp((timeOut/6), function() {
                                faderStat = false;
                                current = items[currNo];
                                if(!mOver) {
                                    fadeElement(false);
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            $(itemsSpan[currNo]).slideDown((timeOut/6), function() {
                                faderStat = false;
                                current = items[currNo];
                                if(!mOver) {
                                    fadeElement(false);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            } else {
                if(!mOver) {
                    if($(itemsSpan[currNo]).css('bottom') == 0) {
                        $(itemsSpan[currNo]).slideDown((timeOut/6), function() {
                            $(items[currNo]).fadeOut((timeOut/6), function() {
                                faderStat = true;
                                current = items[(currNo+1)];
                                if(!mOver) {
                                    fadeElement(false);
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    } else {
                        $(itemsSpan[currNo]).slideUp((timeOut/6), function() {
                        $(items[currNo]).fadeOut((timeOut/6), function() {
                                faderStat = true;
                                current = items[(currNo+1)];
                                if(!mOver) {
                                    fadeElement(false);
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        makeSlider();

    };  

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck, what did you try, what exactly do you need help with? Also I've fixed the style-markup of your question (review pending)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you don't want the captions to be displayed on the slider. It doesn't look like the plugin itself provides a parameter to control this but if you simply remove the `span` element from inside each `li` in the slider it will eliminate the descriptions from showing.

Something like this:

```
  <div id="slider">
        <ul id="sliderContent">
            <li class="sliderImage">
                <a href=""><img src="example_images/410/1.jpg" alt="1" /></a>
            </li>
            <li class="sliderImage">
                <a href=""><img src="example_images/410/2.jpg" alt="2" /></a>
            </li>
            <div class="clear sliderImage"></div>
        </ul>
    </div>
```